# Editing admin credentials after installation

Tags: magento2, installation, credentials

I've just created my first M2 website, but I have made a silly mistake. When I ran bin/magento setup:install command, I've not changed any of the following lines:

--admin-firstname=admin 
--admin-lastname=admin 
--admin-email=admin@admin.com 
--admin-user=admin

Mainly because I did not expect my first bin/magento setup:install command to actually work without any errors. Now I'm stuck because once I try to login to the backend it tells me to set up a two-factor authenticator and that an email has been sent out to me with more details. Obviously, the email that I declared "admin@admin.com" doesn't exist. Is there any way to change that and then re-send the two-factor authenticator email again?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing Magento we need to disable the two-factor authentication module. Try to run these commands in your Magento root folder

```
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth
php bin/magento cache:clean
sudo chmod -R 777 var pub
```

Now login with the same credentials!

If you want to change your admin username and password run the below command after modifying-

```
sudo php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="Admin@123" --admin-email="admin@example.com" --admin-firstname="Admin" --admin-lastname="Admin"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly update your correct email address in the "admin_users" table in the database and do the cache clean.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to create another admin account : php bin/magento admin:user:create.